# Using onchange and onclick together in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

In this code

```
var select = ui.Select({

  items: ['1','2'],

  onChange: function() {  
    Map.onClick(test)

  }
});

Map.add(select) 

var test = function() {

  print ("123")

}
```

When I change the dropdown second time after I clicked on the map the test function runs 2 times , for the third time I change dropdown it runs 3 times after click. I want for every change in the ui.Select after the click the function will run only one time.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but I do see what your problem is. Every time `Map.onClick()` is executed, a new click listener is registered. In other words, every time you change your selected value, you'll add a new listener, and your test function will get invoked one additional time when clicked. The solution is to only invoke `Map.onClick()` listener once.

```
var select = ui.Select({
  items: ['1','2'],
  onChange: handleChange
});

Map.add(select) 
Map.onClick(handleClick) 

function handleClick(coordinate) {
  print ("click", coordinate)
}

function handleChange(value) {
  print ("change", value)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/726f22564980502c05c239639a4639bd

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I have district shapefile of a state and a lulc map. I want to show comparison of different class values between districts. Means comparison of water pixel present between districts again comparison of land pixel present. So I create dropdown of class values. Everytime I choose a class from the dropdown then when i click on the district it shows comparisons in a plot. So I want to place Map.onclick under onchange part. In your code , onclick and onchange works independently. I want to make onclick based on onchange.

Comment: I see. Couldn’t you just ask the select widget for its current value, when clicking on the map? https://code.earthengine.google.com/ba1f6ef2e292eb7ce38025728373a9b6

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I think it will work.